# One Period Binomial Option Valuation Model

Tags: option-pricing, binomial-tree

My question here is how is the probability of an up move calculated by $(1+Rf-D)\over(U-D)$ derived where Rf is the risk free rate, D is the down move factor and U represents the up move factor.

Kindly help me understand the derivation and where this formula comes from as this does not make any intuitive sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the riskneutral probability. What do you know about riskneutral valuation?

Comment: In a risk-neutral world the expected future asset price equals the forward price:

$$p( \, US\,) +(1-p)(\,DS\, ) = S(1 + r_f) \implies p = \frac{1 + r_f - D}{U - D}$$

Comment: @Andrew I am a newbie in the process of learning about valuation of options and other contingent claims and therefore has little to no knowledge about risk neutral valuation.

Comment: @RRL Thanks for the answer. I now understand the algebra behind the equation. Maybe reading further about Risk Netural probabilities will help me better understand it.